# Could not build Objective-C module 'CGtk'

Tags: linux, swift, gtk

I am trying to use swift in archlinux. While attempting to build a simple project with Gtk, I run into some errors. Below is my Package.swift file:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftGtkApplication",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/TomasLinhart/SwiftGtk", majorVersion: 0, minor: 2)
    ]
)
```

And the main.swift file:

```
import SwiftGtk

let app = Application(applicationId: "com.example.application")
app.run { window in
    window.title = "Hello World"
    window.defaultSize = Size(width: 400, height: 400)
    window.resizable = true

    let button = Button(label: "Press Me")
    button.clicked = { _ in
        let newWindow = Window(windowType: .topLevel)
        newWindow.title = "Just a window"
        newWindow.defaultSize = Size(width: 200, height: 200)
        let labelPressed = Label(text: "Oh, you pressed the button.")
        newWindow.add(labelPressed)

        newWindow.showAll()
    }

    window.add(button)
}
```

I am unable to build it with `swift build`:

```
/tmp/swift/.build/checkouts/SwiftGtk--3711260948702777640/Sources/Window.swift:5:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CGtk'
import CGtk
       ^
<module-includes>:1:10: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:

(...)

/tmp/swift/.build/checkouts/SwiftGtk--3711260948702777640/Sources/Window.swift:5:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CGtk'
import CGtk
       ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
swift-build: error: exit(1): /usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /tmp/swift/.build/debug.yaml
```

Both gtk and clang are installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Facing same issue, Please let us know If you could resolve this issue.

Comment: This is now building correctly in my fork, please head to [github](https://github.com/lf-araujo/SwiftGtk) and change the link in SPM to it. Should say that this is with Swift 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple matter of correctly pointing to the CGtk project within the SPM file with:

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/TomasLinhart/CGtk-Linux", majorVersion: 1, minor: 3),
```